# USGS Bulk Downloader 'No JVM could be found on your system'

Tags: java, landsat, usgs, earth-explorer

I installed Java JRE 10 and the bulk downloader successfully but when I run the bulk downloads application it's popping up with the error message[image: error message]

Comment: Perhaps you need a JAVA_HOME system environment variable set? name: JAVA_HOME value: something like C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241 or wherever your JRE is installed.

Comment: i did that before i post the Q, but with no valid solution. still not working thanks for the replay though.

Comment: did you see/try anything on this post?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31838331/how-to-fix-exe4j-java-home-no-jvm-could-be-found-on-your-system-error

Answer (score 1):

For me it only worked after installing the JDK, not just the JRE